# Smtp Email Failure

Tags: python, email

I am new to Python and am trying to test a simple Python script to send emails to myself. I watched a video tutorial and after I completed it I keep getting this error message:
[image]

I Tried to Use PIP to install Smtplib but I also kept getting the error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement smtplib (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for smtplib

I looked online for any help but I am really new so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing.

my code:

```
import os
import smtplib

EMAIL_ADRESS = os.environ.get('EMAIl_ADRESS')
EMAIl_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIl_PASSWORD')

with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()

    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADRESS, EMAIl_PASSWORD)

    subject = 'Testing python emails'
    body = 'This is a test of the python email script'


    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADRESS, 'gonetogrif@gmail.com', msg)
    print("email sent")
```

I used Environment Variables for my email and password

Full error message: gyazo.com/32aa4c8f51922658afc3aaf7a9797d06

Comment: smtplib is a built in library so pip won't install it - is there more to the first traceback?

Comment: The error message seems incomplete.

Comment: this is the full eror message i might of forgot to copy something https://gyazo.com/32aa4c8f51922658afc3aaf7a9797d06

Comment: I Found 1 of the issues, i had a .py file from earlier named email.py, i deleted it and it fixed that probleam but another came up saying

"smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a138sm375577pfd.32 - gsmtp')"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not wrong, however you will need to allow "less secure app access" if you want to send emails from your email address.

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

If you enable this option you will receive/send the email.
[image]

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, i am using 2fa and added a app password but the problem presists